# In how many possible ways can we write $3033030^4$ as a product of 3 positive integers $a > b > c$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many different ways can I write $3033030^4$ as a product of three different positive integers $a>b>c$?

Comment: Do you know how to do it with, say, $100$?

Comment: Hint: factor that number into primes and think about ways to group the factors.

Comment: thx, no Arthur but I can tell you that there are many more...

Comment: Hint: $3033030^4 = (2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot 7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot101)^4$

Comment: So far it is clear but then there is a problem of of repeating themselves when you put together the three groups...

Comment: To clarify, does order matter? (e.g. if we were doing 100 would 4*25 and 25*4 be counted once or twice.) This matters a lot in terms of the counting, so you should make clear which of these the problem is asking for.

Comment: yes I clarify that the three resulting factors must be three different numbers

Comment: CompComp  That's not the question that was asked.  Does $p\cdot q\cdot r = p \cdot r \cdot q =  r\cdot p \cdot q = .....$?

Comment: I'm interested in the three factors without the order, I apologize if I did not explain it well.

Comment: Thanks for the fix ... yes must be: $a > b > c$

Comment: We say that the divisions of the considered number are in total $5^7$ but to find the three factors numbers you have to make some reasoning...

Comment: It is important for you to be clear as can be, *before posting* to state all  conditions that must be met, and/or what counts, etc. (That saves some of us valuable time that could otherwise be used to answer your question, and is otherwise wasted in simply trying to understand the stipulations of the problem. Furthermore, users are more apt to answer question in which the asker has shown some motivation and effort to work on the problem, even if you feel it leads nowhere. In short, we want your participation in our efforts to help you.

Comment: Let me add, btw, CompComp, that you have clearly participated actively in responses and clarification in the comments.  That's a big plus on your side.

Answer (score 1):

As mrnovice says, $3033030^4 = (2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot 7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot101)^4$  You can divide each set of four copies of a prime as $(4,0,0), (3,1,0),(2,1,1), \text {or }(2,2,0)$, each in any order.  Count up the ways to do that, then subtract how many have two numbers that match.  To match, all the primes have to be divided $(4,0,0), (2,1,1), \text {or }(2,2,0)$ and the alignment must match.  Finally, since you want them in decreasing order, divide by $3!$